# Date widget in JQM

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-mobile

```
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mobipick.css" />






<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script
src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="js/external/xdate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/external/xdate.i18n.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/mobipick.js"></script>



 <script>
$(document).on("pagecreate", pageselector, function() {
    var picker = $("input[type='text']", this);
    picker.mobipick();

    picker.on("change", function() {
        // formatted date, like yyyy-mm-dd              
        var date = $(this).val();

        // JavaScript Date object
        var dateObject = $(this).mobipick("option", "date");
    });
});
</script>



</head>
<body>

 <input type="text" placeholder="Last Service Date">

 <input type="submit" value="Book">   
 <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</body>
```

> I am using Mobipick for date, i have these included files in js and css folder of my 
>   project but the calender is not showing up when a touch the date input area on mobile.
>
> I want to add date to my form, I have implementeed it in a project in webstorm through jquery-ui which works fine on the browser but not on mobile

Comment: you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/tML3b/ or create fiddle post your code and libraries

Comment: Saw your code, I want the css and js files to be in my project folder, moreover when i am including the css and js files mentioned in ur code my already used css gets changed and header comes to blue color

http://jsfiddle.net/tML3b/2/

Comment: I just gave a sample not exact one..give the fiddle and tell exactly you want(from your date created dynamically)..

Comment: the fiddle link is mentioned in the prev comment, have a look and please tell me why is the date not appearing

Comment: where you need to show the date.

Comment: the calender must pop out when i click the calender icon in the field just above the "Book" button. I did not get any success in calender icon also, by default the calender must have current date. this is my aim

Comment: check this http://jsfiddle.net/tML3b/4/ and let me know any changes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your fiddle source change the code like following. Include the jquery and jquery mobile libraries in your script

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://mobipick.sustainablepace.net/css/mobipick.css" />


<script src="http://mobipick.sustainablepace.net/external/xdate.js"></script>
<script src="http://mobipick.sustainablepace.net/external/xdate.i18n.js"></script>
<script src="http://mobipick.sustainablepace.net/js/mobipick.js"></script>

<div data-role="page" id="index">
    <div data-role="main" class="ui-content">
        <form action="#" method="POST" id="myForm">
            <label for="CustomerName" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="CustomerName" id="CustomerName" value="" placeholder="Name"/>
            <label for="PhoneNumber" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Phone Number</label>
            <input type="text" name="PhoneNumber" id="PhoneNumber" placeholder="Phone Number"/>
            <label for="Address" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Address</label>
            <input type="text" name="Address" id="Address" placeholder="Address">
            <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                <fieldset data-role="controlgroup">
                    <input type="radio" name="TDI" id="TDI3" value="TDI30" />
                    <label for="TDI3">TDI 3.0</label>
                    <input type="radio" name="TDI" id="TDI4" value="TDI42" />
                    <label for="TDI4">TDI 4.2</label>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <label for="RegistrationNumber" class="ui-hidden-accessible">Registration Number</label>
                <input type="text" name="Registration Number" id="RegistrationNumber" placeholder="Registration Number"/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Last Service Date" id="sdate"/>
                <input type="submit" value="Book"/>
                <input type="reset" value="Reset"/>

        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and your javascript code is like

```
$(document).on("pagecreate",function(event){
        $('#sdate').mobipick({
        dateFormat: "MM-dd-yyyy"
    });
});
```

Refer this <kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/tML3b/4/)**</kbd>

this also [FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tML3b/6/)

Comment: Hello, I saw both the fiddles, one has the black overlay and the other does not. The css and js files in both the codes are the same and the only diff is in the js code, in one event is created on page create and the other is just normal. How does it change the overlay style..??

Comment: @KartikA maybe jquery mobile library issue...check the libraries.

Comment: Hmm yes checked it, works fine but changes by JQM default theme b to some blue colour though :P